# Configuring uglifyjs in Sublime text 2's "Minify" package

Tags: sublimetext2, minify, uglifyjs, sublime-text-plugin

I'm using https://github.com/tssajo/Minify (which relies on uglify for javascript) to minify js, css, html via Sublime Text 2.

I want to use uglify to obfuscate function/variable names wherever possible and running the following via the command line I get the desired effect...

```
uglifyjs --compress --mangle toplevel testJs.js
```

But I can't get the same effect via Minify's "Minify.sublime-settings" file.  By default it contains entries like...

```
"keep_comments": false,
"source_map": false,
```

See https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Minify for more info, but I'm struggling to find the right format to map certain uglify parameters (as detailed here: https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2#readme) to Minify's sublime settings.

I've tried adding things like

```
 "mangle": true,  
 "toplevel": true,
```

But so far I can't get the same behaviour I'm able to from the command line.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After chatting with the creator of Minify the line required in Minify.sublime-settings was simply...

```
"uglifyjs_options": "toplevel"
```